# Pattern for obtaining an element from a Set

Tags: java

I am writing a program that will manage updates to a csv file.
I have a class that represents a csv row:

```
interface Row<K> { K getKey(); }
```

I am currently caching the rows in a `Set<Row>`. The row class has a method to return the "row key", the row key is one or more cells of the row i.e. it could be less than the total number of cells in the row. When the user changes a row - I need to get the row from the cache if it exists and update it. Also, not the 'user' is not necessarily a human user and the user does not necessarily have a complete copy of the csv.

It did not make sense to use `Map<Row, Row>` for this but perhaps that's the only option?

Hence my question - if I have a bunch of classes that share the same "key" is there a way to get an element from the set if all I know is the key. I know I can iterate over the set but this is really inefficient and I want to avoid that.

```
Set<Row> rows= new HashSet<>();

void addElement(Row element) {
    rows.add(element);
}

Row getElement(Row row) {
    // FIXME no get on java.util.Set  --> return rows.get(row);
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example? The code doesn't explain the *problem* at all IMO.

Comment: You want to retrieve the matching object based on its `keyValue()`, correct?

Comment: use a map instead, for instance `HashMap<MyKey, T>`

Comment: If you want a to retrieve objects based on a certain key, you should look into [````java.util.HashMap<K,V>````](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: Please provide a complete example of how you intend to use this class, rather than a broken implementation for it. Or just try to explain what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @ipergenitsa `HashMap<MyKey, T>` requires that `T` is set at the class level, which is not the case here.

Comment: @BalintGyapjas As far as I can read the question, the `HashMap` that you're suggesting is only going to map every instance to itself, which seems kind of redundant.

Comment: Edited the question - hopefully it's clearer

Comment: Is every row in your CSV is supposed to have a "primary key" (consisting of one or more columns)? Are the values that form this "primary key" editable by your users? If *yes* and *no* (respectively), I think you want to maintain a `Map<KeyType, Row>`, so you can get the Row for any unique key, update it in place or replace its value. As your key type seems to be `int`, a `Map<Integer, Row>` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Looks like the Map is the way to go. I'd initially ruled this out since Row is a subtype of KeyType which means Map<KeyType, Row> is esentially a map that contains as it's key information that's a duplicate of Row::getKey which seemed redundant to me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like all you're trying to achieve is a downcast from `MyKey` to a subtype `T` known by the caller for some set of well-known instances that you choose to maintain. If this is really the case, this is how you may want go about it:

```
<T extends MyKey> T getElement(MyKey key) {
    return elements.contains(key) ? (T) key : null;
}
```

The assumption here is that you can use `key1` and `key2` interchangeably, as long as `key1.equals(key2)` holds `true`.

If what you're trying is to always return the "original" instance (the very one previously added to your data structure), you need to use a (weird/redundant) `Map` instead of a `Set`, and map every instance to itself in `addElement()`; `java.util.Map` does provide the `get()` method that you're looking for.

As a side note, be aware that you rely on `equals()` and `hashCode()` being overridden by your `MyKey` subtypes.

However, this seems like a wrong design for pretty much any use case that I can think of, so please consider explaining the actual problem rather than asking how to make a broken implementation (of a probably wrong approach) compile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have edited the question - hopefully it's clearer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve an object based on some key values, a `Map` (with the `HashMap` implementation) is the natural choice of data structure.

But what key should you use in the map?

I'd recommend against a `Map<Row,Row>` although it looks simple and elegant.

Why? This way, you rely on the implementations of `equals()` and `hashCode()` in the `Row` implementations. You want the lookup to exactly compare the key values (the `int` in your example), meaning the `equals()` and `hashCode()` have to use exactly these key values, nothing more and nothing less.

But, comparing exactly the key values might not be the correct `equals()` strategy for each and every subclass of `Row`. And as soon as some subclass changes `equals()` and `hashCode()`, your lookup fails.

Solution:

Create a class `RowKey` that covers the key values (and only the key values), containing `equals()` and `hashCode()`, and use it as the map key (or, if some pre-existing class, e.g. `Integer`, matches that requirement, use that one):

```
interface Row { 
    RowKey getKey(); 
}

Map<RowKey,Row> rowsByKey = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score -2):

Actually java.util.Set collection does not have get method.
Please try to use the following code:

```
<T extends MyKey> T getElement(MyKey key) {
    return (T) elements.stream()
        .filter(key::equals)
        .findFirst().orElse(null);
  }
```

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: That's probably what this comment from the OP was pointing out as well: `// FIXME not get on java.util.Set does not compile`

Comment: You can use the following code
<T extends MyKey> T getElement(MyKey key) {
    return (T) elements.stream()
        .filter(key::equals)
        .findFirst().orElse(null);
  }

Comment: The OP says: *"I know I can iterate over the set but this is really inefficient and I want to avoid that."*